# How can I display the current font H1 is using by JS

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

I'm trying to make a tool for my wordpress site that will show the current styles of certain css selectors.  Ie I would like to show what font (and later color) h1 should be displayed in.

I was thinking of using JS to do this and here is what I started with:

my HTML

```
<h1 id="harold">This is a H1 Heading</h1>
```

then in my functions.php to test I'm using this function:

```
/* Inline script printed out in the footer */
add_action('wp_footer', 'add_script_wp_footer');
function add_script_wp_footer() {
    ?>
        <script>
            var h1ID = document.getElementById('harold');
            console.log(h1ID.style.font);
            console.log("your font is: " + h1ID );
        </script>
    <?php
}
```

Ideally this should output `helevtica your fontis: content of h1ID`.

what I'm getting is `<empty string> your font is [object HTMLHeadingElement]`

I tried this as well:

```
        var h1ID = document.getElementById('harold');
        console.log("your font is: " + h1ID.style.font );
```

which just outputs `your font is:` .

I am doing something wrong, obviously, but is there a way I can query what font should be being displayed here?  Ideally, I would rather just query by "h1", or "p" or etc, but I couldn't figure out how to do that.

Comment: try this as your console : h1ID.style.fontFamily

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The correct style attribute for the name of a font is `fontFamily`.
2. `HTMLElement.style` returns just the inline element styles. To get any styles set through CSS, you need the computed style, returned via `getComputedStyle(elem)`.
3. To get the contents of any HTMLElement, you can use `elem.innerHTML`.

```js
var h1ID = document.getElementById('harold');
console.log(getComputedStyle(h1ID).fontFamily);
console.log("your font is: " + h1ID.innerHTML);
```

```css
h1
{
  font-family: Helvetica;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="harold">This is a H1 Heading</h1>
```

Comment: this works.  is there a way to do it just by calling the h1 selector?  Or h2 etc?

Answer (score 1):

Use [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) to calculate the current CSS style value.
In your case, an example is:

```
const element = document.getElementById('harold');
const fontFamily = window.getComputedStyle(element).fontFamily;
```